# The term for voice effect in orchestral music

Tags: voice, composition, orchestra, orchestral-strings, orchestration

What do we call those voices (it feels like lot of people singing together) in an orchestral music or epic music which make it more **epic**?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel is correct, but I believe the "epic" effect you're referring to (as produced by a choir) is the *chorus effect*.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorus_effect):

> In music, a chorus effect (sometimes chorusing or chorused effect) occurs when individual sounds with approximately the same timbre, and very similar pitch converge and are perceived as one. While similar sounds coming from multiple sources can occur naturally, as in the case of a choir or string orchestra, it can also be simulated using an electronic effects unit or signal processing device.
>
> [...]
>
> It is characteristic of sounds with a rich, shimmering quality that would be absent if the sound came from a single source. The effect is more apparent when listening to sounds that sustain for longer periods of time.
>
> The chorus effect is especially easy to hear when listening to a choir or string ensemble.

Answer (score 2):

Its called a choir, which is an ensemble of human voices.

So I don't have to write a long-winded answer on how a choir works, you can find out more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choir (General choir stuff)

http://www.totalchoirresources.com/lets-talk-choir-formations/ (Choir formations)

Answer (score 0):

It can be either a **Vocal Ensemble** or a **Choir** - **chorale or chorus** or a **Vocal Harmonizer** - **Harmonization effect** (if we speak about singing at different pitches).

If you mean the effect then there are two:

- **Chorus** - In music, a chorus effect (sometimes chorusing or chorused effect) occurs when individual sounds with approximately the same timbre, and very similar pitch converge and are perceived as one. While similar sounds coming from multiple sources can occur naturally, as in the case of a choir or string orchestra, it can also be simulated using an electronic effects unit or signal processing device. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorus_effect
- **Harmonization** - Adding more notes to the melody or the chords in order to make a richer, deeper, wider sound.

If you mean the sound itself then we have two choices:

- **Vocal Ensemble** - The definition of an ensemble is two or more people or things that function together as a whole. A small group of people singing together.
- **Choir** - An organized company of singers, especially one performing church music or singing in a church. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choir

Answer (score -1):

It doubtless IS a lot of people singing together, or an artificial sound designed to emulate this.   But this is an obvious answer.  Are you really asking WHY a choir of voices sounds 'epic', more so perhaps than a choir of clarinets playing the same harmonies?   Mainly our experience of hymn singing, patriotic songs etc. I think.  Rousing or edifing words can add to the effect.